# Why is `this` not working in an ES6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

let obj = {
  username : 'Hans Gruber',
  hello: () => 'hello, ' + this.username
};
console.log(obj.hello());
```

But the output is: `hello, undefined`.

I expect the output to be: `hello, Hans Gruber`.

I think I have not understood `this` in an arrow function. Who can give me a clear explanation?

Comment: It not a doublicate of that question. This here is about Object-Scope

Comment: I'm still puzzled how one can you learn about arrow functions without learning how `this` works in arrow functions.

Comment: Also please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An arrow function saves the binding of `this` in the closure that's created when the function is created. So it doesn't set `this` to the context of the call to the function.

In your case, `this` was bound to `window` when you created the object, so `this.username` is `window.username`, not `obj.username`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **lexically binds the `this` value**

Answer (score 1):

An arrow function preserves the lexical scope in which it was defined. So `this` in your `hello` function is the same as `this` when the function was defined, not the object on which it is a property. It is essentially shorthand for ES5's

```
function() {
    return 'hello, ' + this.username;
}.bind(this);
```

What you want is something like

```
let obj = {
    username: 'Hans Gruber',
    hello() {return `hello, ${this.username}`;}
};
```