# Arrow function in this.helpers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I wonder if someone could explain the difference between:

```
$reactive(this).attach($scope);
this.helpers({
   parties: () => { //arrow function definition
     return Parties.find({});
   }
});
```

and

```
let reactiveContext = $reactive(this).attach($scope);    
reactiveContext.helpers({
  parties: function() { //function definition
    return Parties.find({});
  }
});
```

I have read about arrow function and how it handles `this` (i.e. [why the `this` is not work in arrow function of ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538331/why-the-this-is-not-work-in-arrow-function-of-es6?lq=1))

But in this case, it should not matter how we define `parties` in `helpers`? Because `this` is nowhere present in this example. Am I wrong?

I understand that `arrow function` is useful in the context of:

```
this.subscribe('parties', () => {
  return [
    {
      limit: parseInt(this.perPage),
      skip: parseInt((this.getReactively('page') - 1) * this.perPage),
      sort: this.getReactively('sort')
    }
  ]
});
```

where i.e. `this` (in `this.perPage`) is bound to enclosing context.

Comment: As a side note: I found this article extremely helpful on understanding how exactly arrow funtions work.http://blog.getify.com/arrow-this/

Comment: @Olga thanks, I will read it.

Comment: @Olga great article, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, when `this` isn't used inside the function.

They will behave identically.