# Vue.js Can not see data in console.log

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Today I have to debug my todo App, but can't see the todo array elements in console.log

Code:

```
<template>
<!-- TEMPLATE FOR THE WHOLE APP -->
  <div class="container" @click="deleteTodo">

    <Todolist 
        :todos="todos" 
        :check="check" 
        :updateTodo="updateTodo" 
        :deleteTodo="deleteTodo" 
    />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Todolist from './components/Todolist';

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Todolist,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        todos: [
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Making a cup of coffee',
            checked: true
          }, 
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Making an VueJS todo app',
            checked: false
          }, 
          ....
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      deleteTodo: function(id) => {
        return console.log(this.todos[id]);
      }
    },
    
  }
```

I tried to do it in Parent and child components, but both didn't work, even if I try this.todos.

Also got an undefined message:

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code, still I would say its not enough to debug this issue. We need to see the full code.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan the error occured inside the methode code block, which I used an arrow function at deleteTodo: () => {, I changed it into function() {, and that worked

Comment: That's great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `deleteTodo` as a normal function, rather than arrow function.

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod()). Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

Refer to [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods).

```
      deleteTodo: function() {
        console.log(this.todos);
      }
```

Comment: Why is that. Does Vue.js not allow arrow functions inside an methode code block?

Comment: please check the below part of the link i provided.

Comment: It also contain an undefined after it is rendered. Do you know why?

Comment: @user12380607 May be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538331/why-is-this-not-working-in-an-es6-arrow-function) answer your question

Comment: Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

Comment: @WilliamWang when I use an array id it also show an undefined message, why is that, because the first time he see it?

Comment: what do you mean? array id? since `this` is not allowed in arrow function, you can't use anything with combination of `this.`

Comment: I change it into a normal function(id), but then I want to show the this.todos[id]. The first ourput is the object and the second output is an undefined @WilliamWang

Comment: can you update the codebase in the question?

Comment: also, attach the console.log(id) and display the result

Comment: change it to `deleteTodo: function(id)  {
       console.log(id)
        console.log(this.todos[id]);
      }`
and display the result

Comment: It says NaN and undefined @WilliamWang

Comment: then it is the problem of the other part of your codebase, - Todolist componen.t